# Group rows that match sub string in a column using scala

Tags: scala, group-by

I have a fol df:

```
Zip  | Name  | id |    
abc  | xyz   | 1  |    
def  | wxz   | 2  |    
abc  | wex   | 3  |    
bcl  | rea   | 4  |    
abc  | txc   | 5  |  
def  | rfx   | 6  | 
abc  | abc   | 7  |
```

I need to group all the names that contain 'x' based on same Zip using scala

Desired Output:

```
Zip  | Count |
abc  | 3     |     
def  | 2     |
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please format your code properly. You will find this helpful : https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
Also, share what you have tried already to solve your problem.

Comment: Filter first and then group

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tips @suj1th

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Shaido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shaido mentioned in the comment above, all you need is `filter`, `groupBy` and *aggregation* as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
fol.filter(col("Name").contains("x")) //filtering the rows that has x in the Name column
  .groupBy("Zip")                 //grouping by Zip column
  .agg(count("Zip").as("Count"))  //counting the rows in each groups
  .show(false)
```

and you should have the desired output

```
+---+-----+
|Zip|Count|
+---+-----+
|abc|3    |
|def|2    |
+---+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your help!
I was able to make it work using Ramesh's soln.
I was actually doing a groupBy first than filtering.
Also, why do we need "false" for show?

Comment: false is used to avoid the truncations if the values in columns is long.

Answer (score 0):

You want to groupBy bellow data frame.

```
+---+----+---+
|zip|name| id|
+---+----+---+
|abc| xyz|  1|
|def| wxz|  2|
|abc| wex|  3|
|bcl| rea|  4|
|abc| txc|  5|
|def| rfx|  6|
|abc| abc|  7|
+---+----+---+
```

then you can simply use `groupBy` function with passing column parameter and followed by `count` will give you the result.

```
val groupedDf: DataFrame = df.groupBy("zip").count()
groupedDf.show()
// +---+-----+
// |zip|count|
// +---+-----+
// |bcl|    1|
// |abc|    4|
// |def|    2|
// +---+-----+
```